# Construction of $\sigma$-ring

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X \neq \emptyset$ an arbitrary set and $\mathcal{C}=\{C_1,C_2, \ldots, C_n \} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. My question is if the $\sigma$-ring generated by $\mathcal{C}$ coincide with the ring generated by $\mathcal{C}$.

I know that the ring generated by $\mathcal{C}$ is

$$ R(\mathcal{C}) = \{ A_1 \triangle A_2 \triangle \ldots \triangle A_n \vert A_i \hspace{0.2cm} \text{is a finite intersection of elements of} \hspace{0.2cm}  \mathcal{C}  \}$$

And the $\sigma$-ring generated by $\mathcal{C}$ is the small $\sigma$-ring that contains $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with only a finite number of sets $C_1, \ldots, C_n$,
the ring they generate consists of a finite number of distinct sets, and so any countable union of these is equal to a finite union.

Comment: Thanks, it's possible to calculate the numbers of elements of $R(\mathcal{C})$